# subprocess: PyDev console vs. cmd.exe

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, pydev

I'm trying to call a process from python using subprocess.call as shown below:

```
from subprocess import call

exePath = 'C:\\Test\\EXE.exe'
inPath = 'C:\\Test\\IN.in'
outPath = 'C:\\Test\\OUT.out'
call([exePath, inPath, outPath])
```

This prints a few lines from EXE.exe followed by "The handle is invalid" -- but as a string, not as an error, which makes me think it might be a message from the EXE.exe:

```
Unzipping Solution...
0.0%                       The handle is invalid.
```

However when I open cmd.exe and paste in:

```
C:\Test\EXE.exe C:\Test\IN.in C:\Test\OUT.out
```

it works fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

I'm running Python 2.7 64-bit on Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

It looks now like a problem in PyDev where the console cannot handle the the stdout from the process overwriting lines. The code runs fine from IDLE. Still looking for a fix for PyDev...

Comment: Does it help if you change the double \\ to a single `/` everywhere in your file paths?

Comment: nope, a / gives the same result.

Comment: can you add `shell=True` to `call()`

Comment: Adding `shell=True` gives the same result as well.

Comment: What happens if you combine the in and out files in one arg: `call([exePath, '%s %s' % (inPath, outPath)])`

Comment: That calls: `C:\Test\EXE.exe "C:\Test\IN.in C:\Test\OUT.out"`. The EXE doesn't know how to read that.

Comment: When you run the executable from `cmd.exe`, does it 'overwrite' the '0.0%' text with, say, '1.0%', when it gets 1% of the way through unzipping?  If so, I'd guess that this 'overwriting' may cause the problem.  I don't know how this overwriting works, but it may be that the executable is trying to update text in a command prompt window that isn't there because you're running it from the Python `subprocess` module instead.  Does the executable have a switch that disables this behaviour, e.g. one that makes it generate no output at all?

Comment: Luke, I'm pretty sure you're right about this. Unfortunately the executable doesn't allow the progress to be muted. Anyone have an idea of how to bypass this problem?

Comment: Why not redirect the output from the process to `nul`, using something like `nul=open("nul","wb")` and then in `call([...], stdout=nul)`? I know that in linux this works with `/dev/null` instead of `nul` but I don't know if using `nul` like this in windows works at all.

Comment: I've tried writing the output to 'nul', though it hit's against the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're having this issue because PyDev is not a real terminal (i.e.: in Python, os.isatty() will return False when run from PyDev).

If the exe really relies on having a terminal, currently there's not much that PyDev can do...

For now, you can make your call from Python as:

In windows:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(['myexe', 'params'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
popen.wait()
```

In Linux (as the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is not available):

```
args = ['xterm', '-e'] + ['myexe', 'params']
popen = subprocess.Popen(args)
popen.wait()
```

so that it works regardless of who's calling it :)

I think Aptana Studio does have an actual terminal replacement, but there's no PyDev integration to launch things on it...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. It is still trying to run in PyDev's console.