# Pydev: Send stdout to a real (tty) terminal

Tags: python, console, pydev

Following up on a previous question ( [subprocess: PyDev console vs. cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236260/subprocess-pydev-console-vs-cmd-exe) ), is there a way to change where PyDev sends stdout--namely to a tty terminal?

I've come across several instances where not having a tty terminal has been limiting. For the case of the subprocess module, I can use the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag, but in other instances, such as in this question ( [Print \r correctly in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125692/print-r-correctly-in-console) ), the PyDev console doesn't seem to support using escape characters.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in PyDev.

Comment: Yeah, maybe more of a limitation than a bug (maybe it's related to how the consoles in eclipse are configured?). The PyDev development team seems to be aware of this since they answered my previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a limitation in Eclipse... (which PyDev inherits).

Aptana Studio does have a terminal view which could probably be used as a replacement, but there are no plans to do so for now.

Answering comment below, to create a new shell from a running Python program it's possible to use the code below:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
args = [sys.executable] + sys.argv
new_environ = os.environ.copy()

if hasattr(subprocess, 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, env=new_environ, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    exit_code = popen.wait()
else:
    #On Linux, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is not available, thus, we use xterm itself.
    args = ['xterm', '-e'] + args
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, env=new_environ)
    popen.wait() #This exit code will always be 0 when xterm is executed.
```

Comment: Is there a way to spawn a tty terminal from within PyDev?

Comment: This is for an external process. Is it possible to use a tty terminal for all stdout if for example I want to write code that'll overwrite a line of output such as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125692/print-r-correctly-in-console)?

Comment: How would I add this for a Django project?  Would it go in the managed.py file?  What would I need to comment out or modify in the managed.py file?

Comment: For django you have to patch the creation of the shell. Take a look at: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/2f6735a5e69ed5590ce0e5a6b7b27476bb7c3c9b/plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc/pydevd.py -- look for patch_django_autoreload(), the part which handles patch_show_console == True (note that the latest versions of PyDev no longer have that code, as killing a process in PyDev will no longer leave zombie processes alive, so, that code was removed).

Answer (score 1):

I normally deal with issues like this through the `logging` module in the standard library, which is quite good, but I'll assume you have good reason for wanting this.

I would be surprised if the PyDev console supported full terminal emulation.  At least under Helios on Windows, I've had no problem with Unicode display, but terminal escapes are another matter.

If you know specifically which terminal you want to use, you can run `sleep 3600` in it and then do this in your test driver:

```
import sys
def redirect_terminal(ttypath):
  term = open(ttypath, 'w+')
  sys.stdout = term
  sys.stderr = term
```

Trying this in the interactive interpreter, which will likely be a bit different from running it in PyDev, I get this in the initial terminal (note local echo and prompt still returned here):

```
>>> redirect_terminal('/dev/pts/0')
>>> dir()
>>> raise TypeError
>>>
```

and this in the `/dev/pts/0` terminal:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'redirect_terminal', 'sys']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError
```

While I did not try any terminal escapes here, they are just byte sequences that get printed like any other, so they should be printed on the remote terminal.

I cannot manage to collect input from a different terminal in the interactive interpreter.  When I try, input is still read from the initial terminal.

Comment: What would you use for a ttypath in Windows?

Comment: Not sure.  I think it works very differently in Windows.  Simply opening a special file and replacing `sys.stdout` may not cut it.